# Is there an equivalent of WDIDLE3 / idle3 tools for Samsung or Seagate drives?

Tags: hard-drive

I have 4x Samsung ST2000LM003 drives, 2TB 2.5". They are behaving like what I read WD Greens behave like, i.e. if any power management is enabled then they park heads and spin down after 8 seconds of inactivity.

I'd like to increase this timer. With WD Greens you use the `WDIDLE3` or [`idle3-tools`](http://idle3-tools.sourceforge.net/) utilities to modify the timer. Is there a similar utility for Samsung or Seagate drives?

The standard `ataidle` and `smartctl` timers have absolutely no effect, so I'm guessing the spin down is due to drive firmware.

```
# smartctl -P show /dev/ada0
smartctl 6.6 2017-11-05 r4594 [FreeBSD 11.2-STABLE amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-17, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

Drive found in smartmontools Database.  Drive identity strings:
MODEL:              ST2000LM003 HN-M201RAD
FIRMWARE:           2BC10007
match smartmontools Drive Database entry:
MODEL REGEXP:       ST(1500|2000)LM0(03|04|06|07|10) HN-M[0-9]*RAD
FIRMWARE REGEXP:    .*
MODEL FAMILY:       Seagate Samsung SpinPoint M9T
ATTRIBUTE OPTIONS:  None preset; no -v options are required.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use GoFlex software (as a part of Seagate Dashboard) for Seagate drives (available only for Windows and MAC) Link - https://www.seagate.com/gb/en/support/software/dashboard/

Also, pure Samsung in the storage world is SSD and NVMe.

Comment: I'll mark this as correct even though the docs don't explicitly say so. Their phrasing makes it sound like GoFlex modifies the same power management setting that standard tools change, and that does not affect the timer. Even that feature is Windows only, the Mac version of GoFlex doesn't offer it. Since I have no access to a Windows desktop, and I'm not willing to buy hardware just to plug in over USB which might not even work, I'll just curse Samsung (whose name is largest on the sticker) and Seagate and try something else.